how to import views into oracle database
I have an Oracle dump, which includes tables and views. While importing into the database, it's accepting only tables, not views.
Imp system/system file=test.dmp full=y log=test.txt

am I missing any parameters?
how to import all the object into oracle database?

Do not post duplicate questions
